# If else statement in django template based on request.session data

Tags: javascript, python, django, session, django-templates

I'm trying to prevent/allow the user from clicking a button depending on whether a key is present in the request.session data.

It works for blocking it, but once the key is added to the session, that isn't reflected on the webpage/template and the key remains blocked. I presume I'll have to do this in JS but I'm not sure how to approach it. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
                        {% if choices not in request.session %}
                        <form class="submit-form" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="submit" class="show-more-button cunt" style="margin-left: 5px" name="mybtn"
                                   value="Search" data-bs-toggle="popover"
                                           data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus"
                                           data-bs-content="Please select one or more ingredient">
                        </form>
                        {% else %}
                        <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="submit" class="show-more-button" style="margin-left: 5px" name="mybtn"
                                   value="Search">
                        </form>
                        {% endif %}
```

```
    if request.POST.get('button_color') == 'green':

        selected_ingredients = request.session.get('choices', [])
        selected_ingredients.insert(len(selected_ingredients), ingredients_name)
        request.session['choices'] = selected_ingredients
        request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: Should that be `if "choices" not in request.session` ? (If its presence/absence of `request.session["choices"]` )

Comment: I changed it to that and it's still not detected when choices gets added to the session until I reload. I guess it was blocking it when it was choices without the quotation marks as well cause both choices and "choices" weren't in request.session.